# Nested DIV tables (i.e. table within table), how to build an Object with all the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build an object where each div row can have multiple sub rows

Please run this jsfiddle for the example
https://jsfiddle.net/h55bdxrf/18/

Thanks to jonas Ive got this far using children... so this is what comes out of childs[i] below

```
<div class=​"row chargePartyRow" id=​"1">
    ​<div class=​"col-sm-5 subDesc">​Sub Desc 1.1​</div>
    ​<div class=​"col-sm-5 colour">​Blue​</div>
​</div>​
```

but now final step how do I get the 1 from the id of the first div in the child?

```
    <div class=​"row chargePartyRow" id=​"1">
```

I tried

```
console.log(childs[i].attr("id"));
```

but get I get the error: 'childs[i].attr is not a function'

Also want to get the ​'Sub Desc 1.1' and 'Blue' of the innerHtml

Comment: childs=$fields2.children without the (argument)

Comment: And do childs[i].innerHTML to get the content of the subelements

Comment: Thanks Jonas... just need to get the final values out now... question has beene dited @jonas-w

Comment: To easy childs[i].id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an array:

*if you dont know, an array is a variable that holds multiple variables*

```
var myobj={
children:[
     myobj2,
     myobj3
     ],
 description:"test"
 }
```

You can loop trough all of it with a selfcalling function

```
function check(obj,parent=window){
for(i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++){
check(obj.children[i],obj);
}
//do sth
}
```

Doing the same with the DOM:

```
function check(id){
//do whatever
parent=document.getElementById(id);
childs=parent.children;
for(i=0;i<childs.length;i++){
//do sth with the child
check(childs[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is how to get the children out of the div, I am getting the top level row and now I need to loop through the children but I dont know how to get them using jquery... how do I do it?.

Comment: @John Harrison : ok, your question was a bit unclear for me, edited.

Comment: @John Harrison: did youve tried to use the children property??

Comment: I'm afraid i cant get it to work, can you edit the jsffiddle and show me what you mean?

Comment: @John Harrison : nope. Im on mobile at the moment -> no console -> hard to debug

Comment: OK nearly there with your help please see main question @jonas-w which lookslike the final step of this challenge